# Will the new iPad (bought in Korea) work in the USA?

Tags: ipad, import

I want to buy the new iPad (iPad 3) in Korea with both the WiFi- and cellular service, but I was wondering if this configuration will work on the Verizon Network in the US?

According to Korea's Apple Website the WiFi + cellular specs are:

- Wi-Fi(802.11a/b/g/n)
- Bluetooth 4.0 기술
- UMTS/HSPA/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz); GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)
- 4G LTE (700, 2100 MHz)

Also, I was wondering if it would be unlocked?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it will work in the USA. There is no difference in the hardware for a cellular iPad bought in USA or in any other country.

All iPads have been sold unlocked since their release. So yes, it will be unlocked.

Source: http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/ipad?tqid=Q79JKFTAAKPHKF2FTPT47A24U4YAUH79K

> "Both the AT&T and Verizon model of iPad can roam worldwide on GSM/UMTS networks. In countries without compatible 4G LTE networks, the new iPad will operate on GSM network technologies such as HSPA+ and DC-HSDPA. 
>   When you travel internationally, you can use a micro-SIM card from a local carrier."

Comment: Great content to your answer, but is there any way you could add some sources so we know how you know this? Thanks!

Comment: Aw, sorry, I always forget that!